# get sql.exception error when using session in liferay portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay

I have some problem using session. In view.jsp I get username and password and pass them to portlet class. Then I fetch user info from database and save them in session and go to patientInfo.jsp using "actionResponse.setRenderParameter("jspPage","/patientInfo.jsp")" command. I get user information and print them with the following code:

```
<%  
ResultSet comments = (ResultSet)portletSession.getAttribute("comments");
ResultSet patientInfo = (ResultSet)portletSession.getAttribute("patientInfo");  
patientInfo.next();         
%>
<table>
<tr>
    <th><strong>Patient Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Insuline dose</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="info"><%=patientInfo.getString("FirstName") + patientInfo.getString("LastName")%></td>
    <td class="info"><%=Integer.toString(patientInfo.getInt("InsulinDose"))%></td>
</tr>
```

In this page there is a link that goes to patientProfile.jsp:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="patientProfileURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/patientProfile.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= patientProfileURL%>">Edit Profile</a></p>
```

Everything is ok till now. But when I hit the Back link in patientProfile.jsp to go back to patientInfo.jsp using following code I get "java.SQL.Excqption: After end of resultset" error in stack trace and "portlet is teprorily unavailable" error on the browser :

```
<portlet:renderURL var="patientInfoURL">

    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/patientInfo.jsp" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<p><a href="<%= patientInfoURL %>">Back</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

ResultSets and everything backed by some JDBC Driver are a bad thing to save in the session. Typically they need the database connection in the backend - and the connection will be reused for the next transactions after the first transaction (and page rendering) is done, thus the exception you see.

You should copy over the object you have (how do you retrieve them from the database anyway? Plain/pure jdbc access?) to some business/data-transfer objects that don't have any database connection.

Comment: this is how I connect to database and retrieve data from database:

    java.lang.Class.forName(_jdbcDriver);
    connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUserName, dbPassword);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: Don't do that. Don't keep hold for long time on the results that you get back from the JDBC API - it will limit the scalability of your application and keep resources that could well be released locked. Probably also risking a timeout or - as you see - other problems.